# Почему купол пишется через О?

Tags: орфография

Почему купол пишется через О?

Comment: а какие варианты?

Comment: По-русски "купол", а по-белорусски "купал".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так в оригинале.
Происходит от итал. cupola «купол, свод», из лат. cupula, уменьш. от лат. cupa «бочка».